# Opening TLS Connection fails

Tags: gnutls

I installed `powerthesaurus` package from MELPA. This package finds out synnyms of selected words from `powerthesaurus.org`.
I installed all the dependencies (dom - to be specific which did not get installed by default).

However, when I run the command `M-x powerthesaurus-lookup-word`, I get the following in my *Messages* buffer.

```
Opening TLS connection to `www.powerthesaurus.org'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 www.powerthesaurus.org'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 www.powerthesaurus.org --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect www.powerthesaurus.org:443 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `www.powerthesaurus.org'...failed
```

What am I missing? Why is this connection not working?
I'm able to visit `www.powerthesaurus.org` through my browser

*P.S: I'm using this Windows 7 machine in an office network - if that helps*

Comment: Try running the commands it shows in the console and see / post the output (there should be more of it).